# Learning LISP - Defining a stdev function

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am very new to LISP (so forgive me for any dumb mistakes) and the first lab of the year states:

> Define a function, STDEV that will compute the standard deviation of a list of numbers (look up formula)

I wrote this code but I don't know why it refuses to work:

```
(defun stdev (x)
  (sqrt (/ (apply '+ (expt (- x (/ (apply '+ x)
                                   (length x)))
                           2))
           (length x))))

(setq a '(1 2 3 4 5))

(STDEV a)
```

But on runtime it produces the error:

```
(1 2 3 4 5) is not a number
```

I believe that I have correctly emulated the standard deviation formula (though I wouldn't put it past myself to make a dumb mistake), but why does my program not like the list of numbers that I give it to evaluate? It is most likely a simple mistake with inputs from this new style of coding but any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use indentation. I've edited your question:

```
(defun stdev (x)
  (sqrt (/ (apply '+ (expt (- x (/ (apply '+ x)
                                   (length x)))
                           2))
           (length x))))
```

`expt` returns a number. You call `(apply '+ some-number)`?

Also you subtract a number from a list.

Why?

**Generally I would recommend to use a Lisp listener (aka REPL) to get to working code:**

Compute the mean value:

```
CL-USER 21 > (let ((l (list 1 2 3 4 5)))
               (/ (reduce #'+ l)
                  (length l)))
3
```

Subtract the mean value and square using [mapcar](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mapc_.htm#mapcar):

```
CL-USER 22 > (mapcar (lambda (item)
                       (expt (- item 3) 2))
                     (list 1 2 3 4 5))
(4 1 0 1 4)
```

Compute the variance as the mean value of above:

```
CL-USER 23 > (let ((l (list 4 1 0 1 4)))
               (/ (reduce #'+ l)
                  (length l)))
2
```

Take the square root to get the *standard deviation*:

```
CL-USER 24 > (sqrt 2)
1.4142135
```

Then you only need to assemble it into a few functions: `average`, `variance` and `standard-deviation`.

Comment: My reasoning is that I need to square every instance of the instance of x - the mean:  (xi - xmean)^2. And then sum up all of those resulting values. Because as you said expt returns a number, maybe I need to do the expt within a lambda expression in order achieve my goal of squaring every instance in the list.

Comment: @JohnBucher: but `apply` won't do that. See `mapcar`.

Comment: I am super new to LISP and as such have only gone over mapcar, lambda, and defun and not very deeply either. How could I make it so that the program will take in a list rather than using the list given in code. The first is easy and would be: (defun avg(x)(/ (reduce '+ x) (length x))). But the second part is giving me problems. I don't know what (item) is, if it's important or just a holding name. Then in place of (list 1 2 3 4 5)) I tried replacing it to take in my A list but it doesn't seem to like how I am doing it (list 'x)/('x)/(x), those don't work

Comment: @JohnBucher: make at least three functions: average, variance and standard-deviation.

Comment: I'm nearly finished up just having a problem. My three statements are: (setq a '(1 2 3 4 5)), (defun avg(x)(/ (reduce '+ x) (length x))), and (defun STDEV (x)(sqrt(/ (reduce '+ (mapcar (lambda(x) (expt (- x (avg a) ) 2)) a)  ) (length x)))) which WILL work and produce the correct output, but only because a is hardcoded into stdev as seen here: (expt (- x (avg a) ) 2)) a)  ). I tried changing a to x and then to 'x but the program doesn't like that and throws errors. How do I make it so that the program uses the given list at run time instead of a hard coded one?

Comment: @JohnBucher: You have two variables `x` in `stdev` why not rename one and then get rid of the `a` name. Which input list is `a`? Use the name of the input variable... Probably also  not a good idea to compute the average all the time...

Answer (score 1):

You’re taking `- a ...`, when `a` is your list.

Not a complete answer, because this is homework, but: you want to calculate the mean first, you can implement a sum function, which you will need twice, with a fold, and you can apply a helper function or lambda expression to every element of a list using a map.